# Can't choose any of organiztional repositories in Azure Deployment Center

Tags: c#, azure, github, azureportal

I wanted to deploy angular application to azure web app. I tryed to deploy from github but this app is located in organizational repository and i'm not the owner. So i request the owner and he approved. I thought than know i can choose repository but can not. There are nothing to choose in chekbox - "No result found".
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not the owner of the organization, I think the cause of the problem is the Organization Access.

You need let the owner go to the settings to grand `Azure App Service` access. You could follow the steps in the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-app-service-web-apps-continuous-deployment-with-github-organizations/). And now the App in the page would like the pic shows.
[image]

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem, tried to check settings in my Github account and everything was OK. Then I refreshed the deployment center page, started the deployment wizard all over again, and then suddenly it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In `Authorize` popup, you need to select `Organization access` explicitly before clicking
<kbd>Authorize AzureAppService</kbd>

[image]